# error in initialising vao (glCreateVertexArrays())

Tags: opengl

In order to understand how to use two buffers and binding it to vao i am trying to display a triangle with some color. I am getting an error like this

First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in ConsoleApplication12.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

When i try to debug, this error is caused by  the line in the code

glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);

I did initialized vao, but i do not understand why the error occurred. Please help me..

Here is the code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h> 
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(offset) ((GLvoid *) offset)
GLuint program; 
static int timeFor =0;
GLuint vPos;
GLuint buffer[2];
GLuint vao = 0;
void init()
{
    static const GLfloat positions[] = { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.0f};

    static const GLfloat colors[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

         glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);
         glCreateBuffers(2, &buffer[0]);
         glNamedBufferStorage(buffer[0], sizeof(positions), positions, 0);
         glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffer[0], 0, sizeof(glm::vec4));
         glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
         glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 0, 0);

         glNamedBufferStorage(buffer[1], sizeof(colors), colors, 0);
         glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 1, buffer[1], 0, sizeof(glm::vec4));
         glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
         glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 1, 1);


         const char* vSource = {
        "#version 330\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec4 offset;"
        "layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;"
        "out vec4 fColor;"
        "void main() {"
        "const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0), vec4( -0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0), vec4( 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));"
        "gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID] + offset;"
        "fColor = color;"
        "}"
    };

    const char* fSource = {
        "#version 330\n"
        "in vec4 fColor;"
        "out vec4 fragColor;"
        "void main() {"
        "fragColor = fColor;"
        "}"
    };


    GLuint vShader, fShader;
    vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &vSource, NULL);
    glShaderSource(fShader, 1, &fSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShader);
    glCompileShader(fShader);
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

}

void reshape(int width, int height) 
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(program);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    glewInit();
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);       
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Looks like glew didn't get the `glGenVertexArrays` function pointer. Make sure it is supported in your implementation. Just assuming the function is there is not the correct way to work with GL versions/extensions.

Comment: Enable `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE` see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @Poriferous: Thanks for the reply, I have enabled before initializing glew, that is before glewInit(), but still did not work, throwing the same error

Comment: @spod: And what about the version number/extension support? Have you done anything to ensure that your OpenGL version is 4.5 or the implementation supports ARB_direct_state_access?

Comment: I had suspicions about the OpenGL code. It certainly doesn't look like 3.3 code to me. In the case of DSA, he should use the `#version 450` macro in the shaders. Btw, glut is obsolete so you may want to consider using another Windowing API such as GLFW, SDL etc.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks, thats's the mistake i have done my opengl version is 4.4

Comment: @Poriferous: Thanks for the suggestion, will surely follow the other windowing api

Answer (score 5):

I checked my openGL version its 4.4, in which glCreateVertexArrays is not supported instead of that glGenVertexArrays must be used.